# Do fused weapons count for Shadow soldiers' pristine pool?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Shadow soldiers in the Depths spawn with a random weapon in pristine version.
It's pretty well known that you have to find and destroy a decayed version of a weapon in the overworld in order to make it respawn in the Depths as a pristine one.

But I'm wondering:
If I fuse a weapon (that I never broke before) to something else and break it while it's attached to another weapon, does it still count for the Shadow soldiers' pool?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes, days ago I broke a *Royal Guard's Claymore* which was attached to another weapon.

Recently I found a pristine *Royal Guard's Claymore* in the Depths.